# Photoshop Automation

Tags: vb.net, automation, action, photoshop

I want to run photoshop action through Visual basic UI. i mean if user click on button then photoshop action should run.

can anybody give any hint on that?
thank you

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim appRef
    Dim app
    Dim File
    Dim JavaScriptFile
    Dim nums(2)
    Dim argsArr()
    Dim photoshopApp As Photoshop.Application
    Dim photoshopDoc As Photoshop.Document
    Dim curLayer As Photoshop.ArtLayer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        appRef = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")
        app.load(File("C:\Border-2.atn"))
        app.DoAction(ThisQueue.Dequeue)
    End Sub
```

---

Comment: "but there is something wrong" ?

Comment: @ roryap yes sir this code is not working..please help.

Comment: My point is, what do you mean by "something is wrong"?  How is it not working?

Comment: @roryap error is block variable is not set I have added photoshop object liabrary as reference

Comment: Why didn't you include that to begin with?  How do you expect us to help you when you have such a vague question?  What line is the error being thrown on?

Comment: @roryap  my question can be silly because of I am not a programmer please I want to execute photoshop action through the code my problem is simple that..please understand my problem..I have done my best but unfortunately fail.

Comment: Well, if that's how you ask questions on this site, you aren't going to get much good help from anyone.  I'm sorry, you're question is too unclear.

Comment: @roryap then please tell what should I do to solve my problem

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then come back and write a better question.

Comment: Everything what @roryap said above is true... but giving a blind glance I can say your code is wrong: app.load(File("C:\Border-2.atn")) will fail as app is never initialized.

Comment: @roryap ok sir thanks you for giving your precious time to understand my problem...thanks. I will  try again to clear my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load your Actions or Actionsets within Photoshop first! You can't load or invoke Actions as you've tried it. `App.load (File (...` refers to load images.

```
   Private Sub PhotoshopDoAction(ByVal action As String, ByVal actionSet As String)
        Dim PS As Photoshop.Application

        PS = New Photoshop.Application
        If PS.Application.Documents.Count > 0 Then
            PS.DoAction(action, actionSet)

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: this code is working fine if action is preloaded in action pallet. but I want to load action file in action pallet via code and then execute action

Comment: Unfortunately there are no methods to "Load" Actions via Code. This is not provided by Adobe, and it would be a great source for errors (e.g. At the second script execution, you would have 2 actions with the same name in the same set). Nevertheless, you could do that with the ScriptListener; https://www.kirupa.com/motiongraphics/scripting5.html